# How to push content of a hidden div tag to a table row using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with add more button which adds a certain number of rows with inputs in it. But the HTML string for these rows have grown large enough and its becoming a pain.
So, what I am thinking is to have a div hidden tag with the required HTML that is repeated again and again on clicking the add more button.
So, how to push the div tag innerHTML inside a TR. Below is the code that I need to push, so I kept it inside the hidden DIV tag.

```
<tr>
            <td><label for="bucket_size"><b>1.</b> Bucket Size:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="bucket_size[]" id="bucket_size"></td>
            <td><label for="control_bucket_size">Control Bucket Size: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="control_bucket_size[]" id="control_bucket_size" value="0"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="from_date">Active From: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="from_date[]" id="from_date" class="hasDatePicker"></td>
            <td><label for="to_date">To: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="to_date[]" id="to_date" class="hasDatePicker"></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="location">Location: </label></td>
            <td class="locationSelect">                   
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
```

It doesn't get inserted properly if I directly insert after the particular TR, the innerHTML of the div tag. How to do it?

Comment: Actually div.innerHTML return the above code without the TR and TD tags. So, the table gets distorted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to clone a table row then use another table row, not a div. And don't use innerHTML, use [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode)

```
<table>
    <tr id="clone_me" style="display:none">
         <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
var original_node = document.getElementById('clone_me');
var clone_node = original_node.cloneNode(true);
clone_node.removeAttribute('id'); // Prevent duplicate ID
try {
   clone_node.style.display = 'table-row';
}
catch(iesucks) {
   clone_node.style.display = 'block'; // Should be 'table-row' but need this hack for IE 6-7
}
original_node.parentNode.appendChild(clone_node); // Add new node to end of table
</script>
```

If you find older IE's struggle with `display:table-row` then try toggling `visibility` instead.

Comment: You forgot `clone_node.style.display = '';` and should change the ID as you now have two rows with ID of *clone_me*. :-)

Comment: Is there a way to replace the table structure with something else? Like UL/LI for this case?

Comment: @RodG: nice catch, answer updated. I'm not sure about setting display to the empty string though, is that even legal?

Comment: @akki: it works with any type of DOM element though you'd want to change the display value to something more appropriate.

Comment: @RodG: Ahh I see.. exploit a bug to solve another (http://jszen.blogspot.com.au/2004/07/table-rowsrevealed.html). Setting display to empty string reverts to default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a TR as a child of a DIV, even if the DIV is hidden (it's invalid markup). You can't modify a table by changing its innerHTML in IE < 9 (though you can write an entire table or change the contents of a cell). Use DOM methods.

Likely the best method is to clone a row, then update name and id properties, plus anything else that needs it, and append it to the TBODY. If you append to the TABLE, most browsers are OK but IE will barf, so append to the TBODY.

Extremely simple example:

```
<table>
  <tr onclick="this.parentNode.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true))">
    <td>Here is a cell in a row
    <td>Here is a cell in a row
</table>
```